# Can a Cerberus schema have an arbitrary name for the base dict?

Tags: cerberus

I need to validate Python dicts that will have arbitrary names. When I attempt to validate them using Cerberus, I get `unknown field`. Is there a way of allowing for arbitrary dict names?

I was thinking that `keysrules` might work, but it appears to only work on items within the base dict.

```
{'account_created': {'category': 'Accounts',
                     'conversion_event': True,
                     'description': 'A new account is created'}
}
```

I would like to be able to use an arbitrary name where `account_created` is in this dict.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to validate that base key, I just attempted to answer a question similar to this on the [Cerberus GitHub](https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/issues/498). My suggestion was to maybe use a dynamically formed schema. You could follow the GitHub issue thread and see if anyone there comes up with a better answer.